# indexPath.row всегда выдаёт null

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Подскажите, вот есть такой код, который сортирует словарь по расстоянию, нужно переменную coord передать на detailview где она разделяется на координаты и ставится маркер на карте.Но почему coord выдаёт 0 и как мне передать в неё координаты?

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
 {[self setupArray];
 [super viewDidLoad];}

-(void)setupArray{    self.myLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [states setObject: @12 forKey:@"60.050043,30.345783"];
    [states setObject: @11 forKey:@"60.037389,30.322094"];
    [states setObject: @32 forKey:@"60.037329,30.322014"];
    [states setObject: @1 forKey:@"59.957387,30.324681"];
    NSLog(@"%f",betweenDistance);
    NSArray* sortedStates = [states keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2)
                             {
                                 if ([obj1 floatValue] > [obj2 floatValue])
                                 {
                                     return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
                                 }
                                 if ([obj1 floatValue] < [obj2 floatValue])
                                 {
                                     return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
                                 }

                                 return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
                             }];
    NSLog(@"%@", sortedStates);
    NSMutableArray* rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString* key in sortedStates)
    {
        CGFloat distance = [[states objectForKey:key] floatValue];
        [rows addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", distance]];
    }
    datasource=rows;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 4;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     Detail2ViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
    NSString* coord = sortedStates[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"virable coord %@",coord);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

переделать

```
 NSArray* sortedStates = [states keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2)
```

в

```
sortedStates = [states keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2)
```

тогда массив перестанет быть локальным и всё заработает